# How can I custom indent a file with vim?

Tags: vim, binary, indentation

I recently read [this article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code) related to indenting source files in Vim . However , I would like to be able to custom indent some of them . Is there a way to specify which binary runs when I press = ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the help:

```
={motion}       Filter {motion} lines through the external program
                given with the 'equalprg' option.  When the 'equalprg'
                option is empty (this is the default), use the
                internal formatting function |C-indenting|.  But when
                'indentexpr' is not empty, it will be used instead
                |indent-expression|.
```

It looks like setting the `equalprg` option is what you want.

Comment: Add something like this to your `.vimrc`: `au FileType sql set equalprg=pg_format`

Comment: pg_format very useful to format sql file, especially postgres. After you put modification as bonh wrote above, press gg=G in your sql file to autoformat you sql file. vim is full of magic.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `equalprg`-option. (see :he = for more).